# How to find resources created by CDK (automatically) in AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am try to find resources and their arn which were created by cdk automatically ( like IAM roles and policies as dependent resources)

I can see in the cloudformation physical id there is physical id but there is hyperlink to it like other resources plus I am not able to find those resources by their physical id in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to find those resources by their physical id in the console.

I do not think AWS allows to search by arbitrary text and find proper resource associated with it.

What you can do is print list of resources created by given stack

```
aws cloudformation list-stack-resources --stack-name <YOUR_STACK_NAME_HERE> \
  | jq -r '.StackResourceSummaries[] | [.ResourceType, .PhysicalResourceId] | @tsv'
```

and apply some post-processing to analyze ResourceType and create links for known types.

For example, script below detects IAM roles and EMR clusters and prints links to such kind of resources

```
aws cloudformation list-stack-resources --stack-name <YOUR_STACK_NAME_HERE> \
 | jq -r '.StackResourceSummaries[] | [.ResourceType, (\
   if   .ResourceType == "AWS::IAM::Role" then "https://console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home#/roles/details/"+.PhysicalResourceId \
   elif .ResourceType == "AWS::EMR::Cluster" then "https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/home#cluster-details:"+.PhysicalResourceId \
   else .PhysicalResourceId \
   end)] | @tsv'
```

However, it will require continuous maintenance for this script when you start creating more and more different ResourceTypes

---

Note, `aws cloudformation` has two similar commands - `describe-stack-resources` and `list-stack-resources`. Former is limited, quote from their documentation

> Note: Only the first 100 resources will be returned. If your stack has more resources than this, you should use ListStackResources instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you group the resources together by tagging them with a tag name in your CDK, and then you can find them by tag in the Console?

One other possibility is to use [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html), which shows history of events in your account. The creation of the new resources should show up in CloudTrail.

Comment: I tagged them but honestly by tag not all resources were listed as I can see in the cloudformation.